# HAProxy backend server returns "SSL handshake error"

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I know it's a frequently asked question which often means there's a problem with certificate validation. It doesn't seem to be the case, because I do not verify the certificate.

This is how my server specification looked in the beginning:

```
server 1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com 1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com:443 ssl verify none check resolvers mydns
```

Later it evolved to

```
server 1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com ipv4@1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com:443 ssl verify none force-tlsv12 check resolvers mydns resolve-prefer ipv4
```

But it always returns the same error:

```
Server freehere_maps_redirect/1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com is DOWN, reason: Layer6 invalid response, info: "SSL handshake failure"
```

URL is the real server name. There are 3 more servers in this backend (2.base.maps, 3.base.maps, 4.base.maps...), and all of them return the same error. These servers are not under my control.

I also tried to enable certificate verification, but, of course, it didn't fix the problem. No need to say that `curl` and other attempts to connect to the backend server work flawlessly.

HA-Proxy version 1.8.4-1deb90d 2018/02/08 running on CentOS7.

Your ideas will be greatly appreciated :)

**Update**:
Here is the output of a successful request made with curl:

```
$ curl -v --tls-max 1.2 'https://1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/11/525/761/256/png8?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

*   Trying 13.33.243.105:443...
*   Trying 2600:9000:2118:be00:2:b190:a500:93a1:443...
* Connected to 1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com (13.33.243.105) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=NL; ST=Noord-Brabant; L=Eindhoven; O=HERE Global BV; CN=*.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com
*  start date: May 10 17:54:34 2020 GMT
*  expire date: May 11 17:54:34 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com" matched cert's "*.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com"
*  issuer: C=BE; O=GlobalSign nv-sa; CN=GlobalSign RSA OV SSL CA 2018
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55b593a60020)
> GET /maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/11/525/761/256/png8?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/2
> Host: 1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com
> user-agent: curl/7.72.0
> accept: */*
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
< HTTP/2 200 
< content-type: image/png
< content-length: 30653
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< cache-control: public,max-age=86400
< date: Thu, 03 Dec 2020 12:51:37 GMT
< etag: 4742ccdf6d
< expires: Fri, 04 Dec 2020 12:51:37 GMT
< last-modified: Thu, 19 Nov 2020 20:58:37 GMT
< server: nginx
< x-nlp-irt: D=68945
< x-ols-tid: hjBM-ZZ2dSrOCS0R3IovQk_icd0LanCeb81VKszvSQzzTLygjksosg==
< x-served-by: i-094a2ddaf9791ccf9.eu-west-1b
< x-cache: Hit from cloudfront
< via: 1.1 228e9f9ffd3a938a52da99b2c67d587f.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< x-amz-cf-pop: HEL50-C1
< x-amz-cf-id: gALOyDPx1QY7dsP0NlaEBivgFHjgP8kLWPw5l2U2DfS1ZCEXOg7FDQ==
< 
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
* Failure writing output to destination
* stopped the pause stream!
* Connection #0 to host 1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com left intact
```

**Update2**:
I tried to replace HTTP checks with TCP checks by modifying the backend to:

```
backend freehere_maps_redirect
        http-send-name-header Host
        http-request set-uri http://%[req.hdr(Host)]%[path]?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxx&%[query]
        option tcp-check
        tcp-check connect port 443
        server 1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com ipv4@1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com:443 check
```

tcp-check passes, but I still can't get any results from the uplink server. On the other hand, it may point to a deeper problem, because I get HTTP 400 (Bad request) from CloudFront:

```
<H1>400 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
Bad request.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
<BR clear="all">
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
```

**Update 3:**
Some more details. I tried to use ssldump to view the SSL handshake process. Here's how it looks with haproxy:

```
1 1  0.1478 (0.1478)  C>S  Handshake
      ClientHello
        Version 3.3 
        cipher suites
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
        TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
        TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
        TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
        compression methods
                  NULL
1 2  0.3019 (0.1541)  S>C  Alert
    level           fatal
    value           handshake_failure
1 3  0.3019 (0.0000)  S>C  Alert
    level           warning
    value           close_notify
1    0.3024 (0.0004)  S>C  TCP FIN
1    0.3112 (0.0087)  C>S  TCP FIN
```

And here's the successful exchange using curl:

```
New TCP connection #1: localhost.localdomain(60630) <-> server-13-33-243-73.hel50.r.cloudfront.net(443)
1 1  0.2425 (0.2425)  C>S  Handshake
      ClientHello
        Version 3.3 
        cipher suites
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        Unknown value 0xcca9
        TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        Unknown value 0xcca8
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        Unknown value 0xccaa
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
        TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
        TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
        compression methods
                  NULL
1 2  0.3793 (0.1367)  S>C  Handshake
      ServerHello
        Version 3.3 
        session_id[32]=
          f8 f2 8b 5b 48 eb bb 7f d8 5c 70 e0 9c 86 30 0d 
          f7 3d 6c 52 2f 66 b7 33 84 09 1f bb 25 14 d9 f6 
        cipherSuite         TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
        compressionMethod                   NULL
1 3  0.3994 (0.0201)  S>C  Handshake
      Certificate
1 4  0.3994 (0.0000)  S>C  Handshake
      ServerKeyExchange
1 5    0.3994   (0.0000)    S>C    Handshake
        ServerHelloDone
etc.
```

Does it mean it's the ciphers mismatch problem? But the TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 selected by the remote server during curl exchange is also present in the ciphers list offered by haproxy.

Tried also to add `sni str(d2t4vhngii5504.cloudfront.net)` or `sni str(1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com)`, but it didn't help either.

Comment: Are the certs actually valid? Are you sure your HAProxy server and the backend servers have compatible TLS settings (Ciphers etc)?

Comment: you might be failing due to the check, i would test it forcing a tcp-check using the `option tcp-check` on the backend configuration and explicitly declaring the port to be checked using `check port 443`

Comment: *"... often means there's a problem with certificate validation."* - SSL handshake error is usually unrelated to validation of the server certificate. It is more related to problems with a client certificate, no shared ciphers, unsupported TLS version or missing or wrong SNI. It might be useful to add the successful `curl -v` output to your question in order to better understand the problem. Same is true about details for "other attempts", whatever these are.

Comment: @jstuart-tech, yes, the certificates are valid. They are issued by GlobalSign nv-sa and signed by GlobalSign Root CA - R3. It is possible that the root CA is missing from my store, but I do not verify the certificate

Comment: @SteffenUllrich , I have added the output of curl using TLS1.2 to the question.

Comment: @BANJOSA, I tried to replace HTTP checks with TCP. Results added to the question. Pretty curious.

Comment: Added some more info on SSL handshake process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> server ... ipv4@1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com:443 ssl ... check ...
> ```

The server in question requires SNI. Thus `check-sni name` instead of `check` need to be used. From [the documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#5.2-check-sni):

> **check-sni** 
> This option allows you to specify the SNI to be
> used when doing health checks over SSL. It is only possible to use a
> string to set . If you want to set a SNI for proxied traffic, see
> "sni".

Therefore it should be:

```
server ... ipv4@1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com:443 ssl ...  check-sni 1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work either. My attempt was:
```server 1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com 1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com:443 ssl sni str(1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com) verify none check check-sni str(1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com)```
Handshake failure

Comment: @minaev: the `str(...)` is wrong, just put the name directly. See the updates response.

Comment: Looks like you have finally solved the riddle. I don't know as yet whether resolvers will work in this configuration, but this seems to work: `server 1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com 1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com:443 ssl verify none resolvers hetznerdns resolve-prefer ipv4 check-sni 1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com check`. Thank you, Steffen!

Comment: "instead of `check`" - I supplied both and my server kept getting marked as DOWN due to handshake failures. Using only `check-sni` works flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: @EtienneBruines: Thanks for pointing out the error in the recommended solution. It should not have been both `check` and `check-sni` as initially shown, but `check-sni` instead of `check` as also described earlier in the answer. I've fixed it.